# Axis label obscuring tick label

Tags: plotting

I have a plot and have applied options to customize the axis labels and ticks.

```
Plot3D[{(Bg*l2*l3), 0}, {l2, 0, 20}, {l3, 0, 20}, 
  AxesLabel -> 
    {Style[Subscript[λ, 2], "Text", Background -> White], 
     Style[Subscript[λ, 3], "Text", Background -> White], 
     Style[B[γ] Subscript[λ, 2] Subscript[λ, 3], "Text", Background -> White]}, 
  Ticks -> 
    {Automatic, Automatic, 
     {{-1000000, HoldForm[-10^6]}, 0, {1000000, HoldForm[10^6]}, 
      {2000000, HoldForm[2*10^6]}}}]
```

However, on the vertical axis the label obscures the numbers labeling the ticks. Is there a way to move it upwards so that it's above $2*10^6$?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you rotate the label on the vertical axis:

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], 2 x y},
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 AxesLabel -> {"this is x", "this is y", 
   Rotate[ Text[Style["this is z", 14]], \[Pi]/2]}]
```

[image]

and if you need more space, simply add line returns:

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], 2 x y},
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 AxesLabel -> {"this is x", "this is y", 
   Rotate[ Text[Style["this is z\n", 14]], \[Pi]/2]}]
```

[image]

Which of course works with subscripts:

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], 2 x y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"this is x", "this is y", 
   Rotate[Text[
     Style["Here is \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(text\), \(abc\)]\) with \!\(\
\*SubscriptBox[\(subscripts\), \(xy\)]\)\n", 14]], \[Pi]/2]}]
```

[image]

Or try this:

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], 2 x y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"this is x", "this is y", 
   Rotate[Text[
     Style["Here is \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(abc\)]\) and \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(xy\)]\)\n", 14]], \[Pi]/2]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, the label is still on top of the numbers, since I have a long $2*10^6$.

Comment: @LCF Please see my amended answer.

Comment: Thanks. However, this does not work in my case since I have not a text but an expression with "Subscript[]" as axes labels.

Comment: @LCF It is of course trivial to add subscripts, as you can see.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.